# Sinatra - Render index.html on every request

Tags: angularjs, sinatra, assets, foreman

I'm a little stumped right now, it's one of those moments where my app was working fine yesterday, but all of a sudden it's not, and I have no idea why (I'm sure you can relate).

```
module SK
  module Routes
    class Base < Sinatra::Base
      include Models

      get '/*' do
        File.read 'public/index.html'
      end

      helpers Helpers::API
    end
  end
end
```

I'm building an Angular app, so I need to serve the index.html on every request. This all works fine when I'm using the `shotgun` gem, but as soon as I put it in production using `foreman`, it serves everything, including the assets, as index.html.

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

Here's my config.ru:

```
require './app'

run SK::App
```

So I don't understand why it works in development, but not in production.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shotgun has [its own static server](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun/blob/0.9/lib/shotgun/static.rb) that it will use (to avoid forking when not required). Sinatra will also serve static files if configured to do so, but [using the modular style app disables this by default](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Modular%20vs.%20Classic%20Style).

The fix is to enable the static server:

```ruby
module SK
  module Routes
    class Base < Sinatra::Base

      # add this line:
      enable :static

      include Models

      get '/*' do
        File.read 'public/index.html'
      end

      helpers Helpers::API
    end
  end
end
```

Now Sinatra will serve static files from the public dir before trying to match the route.

Comment: I came back to answer this with a different answer. My `base` class was in a different directory and it seemed to mess with the `root` path, thus messing with the `public_folder` path. But this works, too.